# How to fix 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'keycloak-token' of undefined' error in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, keycloak

I'm trying to use keycloak in my node project but I'm always getting the following message : Cannot read property 'keycloak-token' of undefined.

Before that, I've launched keycloak, I created a new realm 'Test' and a new user 'id_a' which for I've set a new password. I can access to the account with keycloak but I can't with my code. Can you please help me ?

```
var session = require('express-session');
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');
const express = require('express');

var memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();

let kcConfig = {
  clientId: "id_a",
  bearerOnly: true,
  serverUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
  realm: 'Test'
};

let keycloak = new Keycloak({ store: memoryStore }, kcConfig);

var app = express();

app.use( keycloak.middleware() );

app.get( '/complain', keycloak.protect(), function(req, res) {
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(3001, function(){
  console.log('Server started on port 3001...')
});
```

the output is : 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'keycloak-token' of undefined' and I expect hello world

Comment: Where is `keycloak-token` in your code?

Comment: nowhere in my code this is in the following file : node_modules\keycloak-connect\stores\session-store.js

Comment: more precisely there :  "at SessionStore.get (\mini_projet\node_modules\keycloak-connect\stores\session-store.js:24:58)"

Comment: It appears that the problem concerns the following lines in the keycloak-connect module : `function SessionStore (store) {
  this.store = store;
}

SessionStore.TOKEN_KEY = 'keycloak-token';

SessionStore.prototype.get = (request) => request.session[SessionStore.TOKEN_KEY];`

Comment: And apparently this data must be available in the parameter "config" of the function Keycloak but it's weird this isn't specified in the tutorial of keycloak.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The client is not a user account with a password, it's a client in the Test realm you have made. Create a new client, set the Client ID to something like 'node-backend' and then configure kConfig clientId as 'node-backend'.

Clients are applications, like Node, or Angular.

Comment: I get this error on public endpoints when I don't pass in the Authorization header. is this expected behavior for a public endpoint?

Comment: @JDPeckham same question, did you resole it ?

Comment: @asma Sorry, no. We decided not to use this product so I didn't pursue it further.

Answer (score 32):

I had the same issue, but now it's working. You need to instantiate a session before running the keycloak middleware. The missing piece of code is as follows:

```
// Create a session-store to be used by both the express-session
// middleware and the keycloak middleware.

var memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();

app.use(session({
  secret: 'some secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: memoryStore
}));

// Provide the session store to the Keycloak so that sessions
// can be invalidated from the Keycloak console callback.
//
// Additional configuration is read from keycloak.json file
// installed from the Keycloak web console.

var keycloak = new Keycloak({
  store: memoryStore
});

app.use(keycloak.middleware({
  logout: '/logout',
  admin: '/'
}));
```

Checkout the keycloak quick start for nodeJS for full code reference:
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/blob/latest/service-nodejs/app.js

Comment: According to the express-session documentation, the MemoryStore is not fit for production
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session