# How to fix: Cannot read property 'keycloak-token' of undefined in node js?

Tags: node.js, token, undefined, keycloak

I have created realm and client. keycloak json is placed in root folder. still i'm getting the error like,

```
Cannot read property 'keycloak-token' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'keycloak-token' of undefined at SessionStore.get (C:\Users\...\node_modules\keycloak-connect\stores\session-store.js:24:58)
```

```js
var session = require('express-session');
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');

var memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();
var keycloak = new Keycloak({ store: memoryStore });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'keycloak-token' of undefined' error in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56286958/how-to-fix-typeerror-cannot-read-property-keycloak-token-of-undefined-error)

Answer (score 4):

You get this error when you set `app.use(keycloak.middleware())` and don't configure the session store.  The `keycloak-connect` library is trying to read a `keycloak-token` value from the session that hasn't been configured.  You can circumvent the error by supplying an `Authorization` header for example `Authorization: Bearer 123` but the solution when using a session store is to configure it.

For a complete example see `node_modules/keycloak-connect/example/index.js` in your project's dependencies. A minimal example with [resource protection](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#protecting-resources) using [multiple middlewares](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router) in the route handler below.

Be [advised](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) however, that:

> MemoryStore, is purposely not designed for a production environment. It will leak memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process, and is meant for debugging and developing.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const session = require('express-session');
const Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');
var memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();
var keycloak = new Keycloak({ store: memoryStore });

// Configure session
app.use(session({
  secret: 'mySecret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: memoryStore
}));

// Attach middleware
app.use(keycloak.middleware());

// Attach route handler for home page
app.get('/', keycloak.protect(), (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({status: 'ok'})
})

// Start server
app.listen(3005)
```